# Display Modal window using a cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies, modal-dialog

I am trying to make a modal window display once per session using cookies.
With the below code, alert box gets displayed fine once per session but if i place the modal code, it does not work.

```
if ($.cookie('modal') != 'shown') { 
    $.cookie('modal', 'shown'); 
    alert("message");
}
```

In place of alert("message") I am placing the below modal code:

```
$("#dialog-modal").dialog({ 
    height: 750,
    width: 1045,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false
});
```

Comment: You mean that the modal box does not appears at all, or it appears independently of the cookie?

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure you have your jQuery code wrapped in a `$(document).ready()` function call, ie:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dialog-modal").dialog({ 
        height: 750,
        width: 1045,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false
    });
});
```

Comment: I dont have the $(document).ready in the code. should I include that as well and replace the alert("message"); The way I am using the code is <script>

    $(function() {
        $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
            height: 750,
            width:1045,
            modal: true,resizable:false,draggable:false
        });

    });   


 </script>

Comment: I dont have the $(document).ready in the code. should I include that as well and replace the alert("message"); The way I am using the code is. The modal window shows up with the cookie but cookie part does not work

 <script>

    $(function() {
        $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
            height: 750,
            width:1045,
            modal: true,resizable:false,draggable:false
        });

    });  

 </script>

Comment: `$(function () {...});` is equivalent to `$(document).ready(function () {...});` so you're good there.

Comment: You should be seeing some kind of error (use console in Firefox or Chrome).